# Time complexity of a nested loop

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I need to figure out the complexity of the following loop in theta notation but I can't figure it out. Some help would be much appreciated.

```
from j := 1 until j > n loop
  from k := 1 until k > n*n*n loop
     k := k + j
  end
j := j + 2
end
```

some help with an explanation would be much  appreciated. The solutions state $\theta(n^3log(n))$. it is clear that the second loop executes $n^3$ times but where does the $log$ come from?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Check out [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis) . See if you can write out how many times the inner loop will execute based on the outer loop (e.g. when $j=1$, the inner loop runs $x$ times, when $j=3$ the inner loop runs $x'$ times, etc.) then you might be able to find a pattern or summation.

Comment: That question, and others tagged [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops].

Comment: Please check your source code. It cannot be log. Maybe j := j / 2 ?

Comment: @fade2black, it is $n^3 \log n$, the solution is correct. ([Harmonic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) $H_n = \Theta(\log n)$) Write out the summation and you should see it.

Comment: @ryan The outer loop is the sum of odd numbers. The inner loop is always $n^3$.

Comment: @fade2black $j$ is also affecting the inner loop. The summation would be $$ \begin{align} T(n) & = n^3 / 1 + n^3 / 3 + n^3 / 5 + \dots n^3 / n \\ & = n^3 \cdot (1 + 1/3 + 1/5 + \dots + 1/n) \\ &= n^3 \Theta( H_n) \\ T(n) & = \Theta( n^3 \log n) \end{align}$$

Comment: @ryan could u please send me the line in the inner loop? Is it k = k + 1?

Comment: @fade2black it is "k = k + j" in the inner loop.

Comment: @ryan I don't quite understand why do you say (1 + 1/3 + 1/5 +... + 1/n)? why do you divide?  Could you please explain? I get that the inner loop also depends on j and j is (1,3,5,7,.....), so in a way, we need to find out how fast k approaches $n^3$, but I don't follow the rest. Thanks

Comment: @DariusTheGreat, the first time the inner loop is executed it increments by 1, then by 3, then by 5, then by let's say $x$. Each time it iterates to $n^3$, so we clearly take $n^3/x$ steps to get there.